# Display & Add Grandchildren in Django Admin

Tags: python, django

We have 3 tables defined in models.py:

`class country(models.Model):
    country_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)`

class region(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(country)
    region_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    region_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class school(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(region)
    school_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

We would like to be able to add a country, then in the same admin screen, add a region, then add a school within that new region. All fairly basic stuff and doing the first step of adding a country then a region can be done by adding these lines to admin.py:

`class RegionInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = region
    extra = 1`

class CountryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [RegionInline]

admin.site.register(country, CountryAdmin)

Unfortunately we cannot work out how to even display schools in the same screen as adding/editing a country.

We have also considered looking at it from the perspective of the schools and having the country and region inline, but have the same basic problem of not being able to display the country because it is not directly linked to the school.

So, in a nutshell, our question is:

Using the Django admin process how are records displayed & added that are not directly linked to the current model?

We very much suspect that the answer to this question is explained somewhere in the great Django documentation but we are new to Python/Django and can't find it, so if anyone can point us in the right direction then that would be great and save re-inventing the wheel.

Python v2.7, Django v1.7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current version of django [doesn't support](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9025) third level of inlines in admin.

You have to use the [django-nested-inline](https://github.com/s-block/django-nested-inline) app.

Comment: Thanks, I have marked your response as the answer. I must admit to being disappointed though, in that I expected django to support what is a very common task in the same straightforward fashion as it does the really easy stuff, but that appears to be its limit.